# Creating a Query or SQL Statement from multiple lists30

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, query

I have built out the back end of my database with multiple related tables.  What I'm trying to do now is build a view that pulls from those tables based on the relationships and a combo box filter.  This was really easy to do in access, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with sharepoint 365.

The lookup fields only let me go one layer deep and I can't pull people columns or lookups from the related table.

Thanks

Comment: That’s SharePoint... it always gets you about 90% there, then you find something that “ought” to work... and it doesn’t. You have to cobble together crazy duplicate fields and workflows to copy data around to coax it to work... sorry, had to rant... I’ve been working with SharePoint since 2003... lists have never gotten much love over the years from MS. Very few enhancements.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it's not just me.  I'll spend half the day saying SharePoint is awesome, then the next two days trying to get it to something super simple on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm trying to do now is build a view that pulls from those tables based on the relationships

The easiest way to do this is by creating a view in SQL Server and just use that as the source for your External List.

Can you supply a bit more detail about your project?

Comment: I have a list of projects, then a list of design packages with a lookup to the jobs, then a list of drawings with a lookup to the design package, then a list of tasks associated with each drawing page.   What I would do in Access is build a query for the data and have a form with a combo box to filter the data by the manager associated with each project to see all of their tasks.  I can't seem to figure out how to do that in sharepoint, mostly from inability to figure out where/how to build a query in it.